# How can i set "No JAVA_HOME Environment Variable set. Trying to guess it..."?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, boilerpipe

i am trying to install python library(boilerpipe):
pip install boilerpipe.
But i am getting the error:
"No JAVA_HOME Environment Variable set. Trying to guess it..."
which was i already set the java path.
So what can i do for this????

Comment: go to command prompt and try "java -version" command if you could some value your java is installed properly and then check "PATH" environment variable does it have java home path added?

Answer (score 0):

Check [here.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows)
You didn't set up JAVA_HOME. You might add the java bin in the system path. You need to create JAVA_HOME variable. Check the link above.